# Google Map Result as XML or JSON

Tags: google-maps

I have this url to view the nearest hospitals with the given coordinates.

```
http://maps.google.com/maps?q=hospitals+near+{lat},{long}
```

Is their a way to get the results in XML or JSON?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have lots of options, starting [here](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/).  IF you want a URL you can query and get back XML or JSON then go [here](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/webservices/).

Those are links directly to the Google APIs documentation.  You have many options available including a JavaScript API as well as a web service that can retrieve JSON or XML.

Comment: I'm looking for if any, some kind of a type parameter that would convert the result like
http://maps.google.com/maps?q=hospitals+near+{lat},{long}&format={xml|json}.

Comment: All the information is in the documentation I linked.  What part are you having a hard time with?  https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/places/

Comment: Here ya go, this is a URL, straight from the documentation: `https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/search/json?location=-33.8670522,151.1957362&radius=500&types=food&name=harbour&sensor=false&key=AddYourOwnKeyHere`  hospital is valid as an argument for `types`